# Android kernel error: undefined reference to `radio_hci_smd_init'

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, arm

I am trying to build Android kernel for Motorola Moto E.

**Android Kernel Info:**

Name: Android Kernel Motorola MSM8610

Device(Intended): Moto E

Hardware: MSM8610

Github: [Kernel Source Link](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_motorola_msm8610)

**Toolchain:**

I have tried this on the following toolchains with the same error.

1. [Linaro 4.6.4](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=36677987)
2. [Android NDK ARMEABI 4.6](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html)

**My Procedure:**

1. First cleaning the android kernel source directory.

   `make clean && make mrproper`
2. Making the config file.

   `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/toolchain/bin/ msm8610_defconfig`
3. Building the kernel.

   `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/toolchain/bin/`

**The Error:**

On the last step, i.e. the Building the kernel part, I am getting the following error:

```
  LD      init/built-in.o
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux1
drivers/built-in.o: In function `iris_fops_open':
/home/mohit/code/android_kernel_motorola_msm8610/drivers/media/radio/radio-iris.c:5100: undefined reference to `radio_hci_smd_init'
Makefile:885: recipe for target '.tmp_vmlinux1' failed
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1
```

So can this be fixed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you know your way around the kernel sources, this is very straightforward to investigate by just following the trail:

- A search reveals `radio_hci_smd_init` is defined in [radio-iris-transport.c](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_motorola_msm8610/blob/2f86d79dbdaa14a59e2835bc4705b01ccdbbdbcb/drivers/media/radio/radio-iris-transport.c#L200-L203)
- Stepping out to the Makefile, radio-iris-transport.c is built [dependent on CONFIG_RADIO_IRIS_TRANSPORT](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_motorola_msm8610/blob/2f86d79dbdaa14a59e2835bc4705b01ccdbbdbcb/drivers/media/radio/Makefile#L33). Therefore there's probably some config problem.
- The KConfig entry for RADIO_IRIS_TRANSPORT turns out [to be disabled by default](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_motorola_msm8610/blob/2f86d79dbdaa14a59e2835bc4705b01ccdbbdbcb/drivers/media/radio/Kconfig#L461), so it's probably down to the defconfig.
- Bingo. [That defconfig is bogus](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_motorola_msm8610/blob/2f86d79dbdaa14a59e2835bc4705b01ccdbbdbcb/arch/arm/configs/msm8610_defconfig#L384-L385) - RADIO_IRIS is built-in, but RADIO_IRIS_TRANSPORT is being built as a module. Module code is compiled separately after the main vmlinux image and thus not available to link with.

The simplest approach would probably be to edit your .config to change `CONFIG_RADIO_IRIS_TRANSPORT=m` to `CONFIG_RADIO_IRIS_TRANSPORT=y`, to make that driver also built-in and hopefully able to link with the other one.

That said, the line giving your error [isn't even there in the branch I'm looking at](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_motorola_msm8610/blob/2f86d79dbdaa14a59e2835bc4705b01ccdbbdbcb/drivers/media/radio/radio-iris.c#L5100). From the Git log, it seems like somebody tried to fix a broken runtime dependency problem by introducing a broken build-time dependency instead, and on that branch at least it was reverted again.

Comment: Thank you that fixes it. Your trail debugging was really helpful.